# Remove 30MB upload limit on IIS express

Tags: .net, iis, iis-express

Does anyone know how to remove the 30MB upload limit, specifically for IIS Express?

I've tried editing the applicationhost.config and

```
 <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1050000"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

<location path="api/media/AsyncUpload">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1050000" /> 
<!-- The size specified is in kilobytes. The default is 4096 KB (4 MB). 1gb = 1048576 -->
        </system.web>
      </location>
```

Seem to be set correctly?

Any ideas?

Comment: maxAllowedContentLength set in BYTES.  maxRequestLength in KILOBYTES

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should change the server config file. The field you are looking for is

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```

If it doesn't exist, adding it  should override the defaults.

Comment: Whoops was setting that in KB, not B :)

Comment: By the way, the config file is at this place : ~\Documents\IISExpress\config