# Asp.net Core 2.0 RequestSizeLimit attribute not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I'm creating a website in Asp.net core 2.0 which allows files to be uploaded.  I quickly came across the problem of the `30MB` upload limit and receive a `404` response from the server.  Below this limit everything works fine.

I found a number of solutions on the web like this one:
[Increase upload file size in Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core). My problem is that I cannot get this solution to work and I'm still getting the `404` response when over `30MB`.

My call is an ajax one and goes like this:

```js
function uploadMedia(isPhoto, files) {
  var type;
  if (isPhoto) {
    type = "i";
  } else {
    type = "v";
  }

  var data = new FormData();
  if (files.length > 0) {
    for (idx = 0; idx < files.length; idx++) {
      if (files[idx].size < 1074790400) {
        data.append("fileImage" + idx, files[idx]);
      } else {
        BootstrapDialog.show({
          type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
          title: "Validation Error",
          message: "The maximum file size for images is 1GB. Please resize your image and upload again.",
          buttons: [
            {
              label: "OK",
              action: function(dialogItself) {
                dialogItself.close();
              }
            }
          ]
        });
      }
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/article/uploadfile/" + type,
      type: "POST",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      dataType: false,
      data: data,
      success: function(jsonData) {
        refreshUploadedImages(jsonData, isPhoto);
      }
    });
  }
}

function rotateImageAnticlockwise(element) {
  var id = $(element).attr("data-id");
  var mediaData = getMediaData(id, true);

  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/article/rotateMedia/a/p/" + mediaData.fileId + "/" + mediaData.rotation,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(jsonData) {
      refreshRotatedImage(jsonData);
    }
  });
}
```

Then my server-side method has attributes like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestSizeLimit(1074790400)]
[Route("api/article/uploadfile/{mediaType}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(string mediaType)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  This is driving me mad!!!

Comment: Just a thought, as a troubleshooting step, have you tried 1) commenting out your JS `if (files[idx].size < 1074790400)` block (just the surrounding block so the `data.append` executes and 2) using `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` on the action method (instead of setting an explicit limit)?

Comment: @egnomerator - I tried both but still get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Just to be sure I'm not making incorrect assumptions, your app is hosted by IIS and not self-hosted? Sorry if this was specified somewhere and I missed it.

Comment: I am running the website from Visual Studio as a standard .net core 2.0 asp.net app.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For anyone else with the same problem, this is the answer.

Mark LaFleur's answer was the right direction but the web.config was missing a crucial section.

I was helped but this webpage that explains more about the web.config file in Asp.net Core:
[ASP.NET Core Module configuration reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

To stop this error you need to create a web.config file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- This will handle requests up to 50MB -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm! Do you know another way to fix the same issue without creating the web.config? I mean from the code itself or if we can do it from the built-in appsettings.json in the ASP CORE project.

Answer (score 8):

The `RequestSizeLimit` attribute allows you to define the maximum request size within your code but it is still limited by maximum request size supported by the server itself.

In this case, I suspect you're receiving this error:

```
HTTP 404.13 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.
```

This error is being triggered by ISS because the call exceeded IIS' `maxAllowedContentLength` value (the default is `30,000,000`). From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1#troubleshooting):

> The following error indicates your file upload exceeds the server's configured `maxAllowedContentLength`. The default setting is `30000000`, which is approximately `28.6MB`. The value can be customized by editing the `web.config`:
>
> ```xml
> <system.webServer>
>   <security>
>     <requestFiltering>
>       <!-- This will handle requests up to 50MB -->
>       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
>     </requestFiltering>
>   </security>
> </system.webServer>
> ```

Comment: I did try to add a web.config like this but then I encountered another problem.  When I try to run the app from Visual Studio I get the following error: 'The web server request failed with status code 500.  Internal server error.  Then the full response says 'HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.'

Comment: This could be caused by a number of settings. More often than not it turns out to be a feature in ISS isn't installed on the server. Which version of IIS are you using to host the site?

Comment: I'm not trying to deploy the app to a server, just trying to run it from Visual Studio

Comment: Take a look at the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11961615/105518. It sounds like IIS Express requires overriding it's default config. Another option would be to use a local IIS instance instead of IIS Express.

Comment: Also, if you're just using Kestel without IIS you may want to take a look at these options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.1#kestrel-options