# ASP.NET Core HTTP 404 on a large request

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I am getting HTTP 404 when I call an api method. The request is over 30MB in size. When I call the same api method with smaller data, the method processes successfully. The only difference is the size of the request.

Since the default request size is now ~ 30MB in ASP.NET Core 2.0 (https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267) I tried setting the attribute `RequestSizeLimit` to 100MB, but I am still getting the error even with this attribute.

```
[HttpPost("validate")]
[RequestSizeLimit(100000000)]
public List<XmlValidationError> Validate([FromBody]XmlDocumentDto order)
{
    ...
}
```

I trie also setting `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` on the method but it did not help.

How can the maximum request size be set?

Strangely, the 404 is also accompanied with a CORS error:

[image]

Comment: Hi did you find workaround? ... yesterday I got same issue. initially I didn't use [RequestSizeLimit], only [DisableRequestSizeLimit]. That issue are reproducing on Azure App service, but not locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `RequestSizeLimitAttribute` was not enough. What helped was adding a `web.config` as described in [Asp.net Core 2.0 RequestSizeLimit attribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220880/asp-net-core-2-0-requestsizelimit-attribute-not-working?noredirect=1).