# Error: 413 Request Entity Too Large using Vuetify

Tags: .net, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I'm trying to upload large files and I get the error: 413 Request Entity Too Large.
I can't find any solution, how can I set the maximum file size?

I'm using vuetify@2.4.2 as fron-tend and .NET 5.0 as back-end.

Here is a sample code that uploads the file (note: I use Axios Post)

```
const formData = new FormData();
this.Files.forEach((element) => {
 formData.append("files", element);
});
formData.append("json", JSON.stringify(this.FileInfo));

var res = await utils.doPost("/Files",formData);
```

Comment: Where do you host your solution? nginx?

Comment: @MichałT I'm using IIS.

Comment: @MichałT But also I want to be able to use it while running on Visual Code as localhost.

Comment: Please check if this answer is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63363499/10917343